# how to run code in tabbarcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

Im trying to change the icon tint of my unselected tab bar icon images.  I have used the patch code below, however, the post that i found this patch code in says to run this in the tab bar controller but i did not know how to do that so i ran it in the -(void)viewDidLoad method in the viewcontroller .m file. It came up with an error saying "Property 'tabBar' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'"  How do i fix this?

```
// set color of selected icons and text to red
self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


// set color of unselected text to green
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor greenColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// set selected and unselected icons
UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

// this way, the icon gets rendered as it is (thus, it needs to be green in this example)
item0.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected-icon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

// this icon is used for selected tab and it will get tinted as defined in self.tabBar.tintColor
item0.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-icon.png"];
```

Comment: Where are you creating `UITabBarController`? In Interface Builder?

Comment: If you used the xcode template the tabbarcontroller is in your appdelegate.

Comment: @StasDerpoliuk well the thing is i just put a tab bar on my main view controller that shows up in storyboard by default.  should I delete this view controller and put a uitabbarcontroller?

Comment: @Hackmodford i am using xcode template but as you see in the comment above i just dragged a tab bar onto my main view controller.  If you guys think i should delete that and make a iutabbarcontroller then i will and i'll drop this code into my appdelegate.m fle. If i do that do i need to address it in my appdelegate.h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete your `UIViewController` from storyboard and add there `UITabBarController` and set it as `Initial View Controller`.

Then you can access this `UITabBarController` in `AppDelegate.m` like this:

`UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;`

This is the fast way.

Also you can subclass `UITabBarController`, set this class in the storyboard and put all your code inside this subclass. (as null has said 15 minutes before :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that patch of code, try to do the below in your VC:

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_seleted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"item_unselected.png"]];
```

Edit:

The code above is used when subclassing `UITabBarController`, so if you insis you need to subclass the 'UITabBarController', change the class of your tabBarController in the storyboard and put that block of code in its `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks null but I am trying to change the icon tint of my UNselected icons

Comment: Ok this will do the job, it will change the unselected tab icon, by the way you can't change the tint color, you must change the icon to do that.

Comment: it says that it has been depreciated in ios7

Comment: Null, how do I change the class of my tabbarcontroller?

Comment: @user2792129 "Identity inspector" tab in the "Utilities" panel.